# JQuery UI Autocompletion - Adding a action link to each result item

Tags: jquery, image, hyperlink, label, jquery-autocomplete

i would like to modify my resultlist in the jquery UI autocomplete component in such a way, that i achieve the following:

label   resulting_text       actionlink

Is that somehow possible or do i need to do some monkey-patching? If monkey-patching is the action, where do i get a resource to look how this can be modified?

Thank you for your thoughts,
Ramo

Comment: Would a bit more fair to accept answers of people who take time to help you out...

Comment: hi, i really can't remember that you tryed to help me with this problem. i'm sorry about that, and as i a see, the above structure is broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you would like to do this for all the autocomplete components on the page, I'd modify the "_renderItem" property. It is a function that is called by jquery UI to render each of the items on the list that is shown to the user with the results.

I've done something similar to this in one of my projects. Here is the code I used:

```
$.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    return $('<li />').data('item.autocomplete', item).append('<a>' + item.toString().htmlEncode() + '</a>')
        .appendTo(ul);
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer... this gives me a first hint where to start... my structure above where broken.. so what i would like to achieve is something like "label resulting_text actionlink", where resulting_text is the textual representation of the found item, label can be the category and actionlink an alert for example