# jquery autocompletion get clickable link per item

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, hyperlink, label

i'm using a solr instance as a datasource for the jquery autocompletion ui plugin. from the request i get a label and an id for the search value back as a json string. currently both values are displayed in the autocompletion box, e.g. if a type  "re" i get a label where "re" is in and the id of that item in two seperate rows, e.g.

res

12

what i would like to achieve is to get only the item label as a link and the id as a parameter for that link, so if i search for "res" that i get just ONE list entry as a link and if i hover it that i get a link like: http://mydomain.com/result/12

one solution i thought would work is on [JQuery UI Autocompletion - Adding a action link to each result item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467689/jquery-ui-autocompletion-adding-a-action-link-to-each-result-item) .
even with this solution i get two list result (the searchterm result and the appropriate id)

i modified the code from the above link to:

```
$("#product").autocomplete({
            source: '{{ path('MyRemotSource_search') }}',
            minLength: 2,

        })
     $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
         return $('<li><li />').data('item.autocomplete', item)
        .append('<li></li>').add('<a href="http://mydomain.de/result/'+item.value+'">'+ item.label+ '</a>')
    .appendTo(ul);
         };
   });
```

I would appreciate any help for this issue.

Best regards,
Ramo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    var a = $('<a>', {
        href: "http://mydomain.de/result/" + item.value,
        text: item.label
    });
    var $li = $('<li>');
    return $li.append(a).data('item.autocomplete', item).appendTo(ul);
};
```

I setup a remote call just for the show you that it works

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/sRyfq/

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer. i'm not getting it 100%. have to look what all that ajax definition are, that you made.

Comment: @ramo the ajax part was only to have some data and set-up the fiddle, should work with any source that provide objects with label and avlue

Comment: i guess my problem are the results i get from solr. i still get the double entries (id and label) in two seperate rows. how does a json string have to look like? or do i need a jsonp object?

Comment: a single item should be  `{ label: "Mil, Guinea-Bissau", value: "Mil"}`, probably the problem is in what solr returns

Comment: so, could i return an array where a gather the results i get from solr, like this: array(20) { [0]=> string(50) "{"label":"HP  1GB DDR2-400 ECC reg","value":"978"}"  [1]=>  string(50) "{"label":"HP Memory 4GB REG PC2700","value":"998"}" etc. ? Or do i need some extra steps on javascript side now?

Comment: okay, that's doing the half job. now i see the labels in the autocomplete list, and if i hover over a label i see in the link the url with the id at the end. the only problem now is, if i click on one item, i get the id into the inputfield, and don't get redirected to the page the <a> tag is refereing to

Comment: Hey nicola, does your push buttons still work if you use this above code? i mean the push buttons on the keyboard (down button)

Comment: Yes, in this example i didn't include jQuery ui css and so you could not see that, look here http://jsfiddle.net/sRyfq/1/

Comment: but if i click on a search entry in your example nothing happens, but you defined each entry as an <a> element, didn't you?

Comment: hi nicola, for the source i don't use the jquery ajax. my code looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/GeVnN/1/   i can't give you the url, because i'm invoking a php method that builds the query and get the following as a result: [{"label":"Tosca","value":"605243","thumb":""},{"label":"Tos...] now i want the same behaviour if i click on an list entry, or if i use my keyboards push buttons and enter, any idea?

Comment: @ramo i think you'd better open another thread on stackoverflow!

Comment: nicola: did it already, but somehow this is more confusing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929104/jquery-ui-autocomplete-js-error-on-keydown