# jquery ui autocomplete js error on keydown

Tags: autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

i've included the jquery ui automcomplete plugin into the following structure:

```
<li class="search">
                            <input type="text" class="searchfield" name="searchfield" value="Search for Products" />
                        </li>
```

my javascript for this input field looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function addSearchFieldFunctionality() {

var availableTags = [
                    "ActionScript",
                    "AppleScript",
                    "Asp",
                    "BASIC",
                    "C",
                    "C++",
                    "Clojure",
                    "COBOL",
                    "ColdFusion",
                    "Erlang",
                    "Fortran",
                    "Groovy",
                    "Haskell",
                    "Java",
                    "JavaScript",
                    "Lisp",
                    "Perl",
                    "PHP",
                    "Python",
                    "Ruby",
                    "Scala",
                    "Scheme"
                ];  
$('.searchfield').each(function () {
    $(this).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags,
            minLength: 1


        }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
            //console.log(item);
            var a = $('<a>', {
                href: item.value,
                text:  item.label,
                "class" : "mySearchClass" 

            });
            var b = $('<a>', {
                href: item.value,
                text: "Add", style: "float:right"});


            var $li = $('<li></li>', {style:"width:100%"});
              return $li.add(a).appendTo(ul);
        };
});
}
</script>
```

I'm loading that function on document ready. for some reason, if a start typing e.g. the first three letters of a item, i get a resultlist. as soon as i push the keydown push button on the keyword, i get the following error in the chrome (latest version) console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null
a.widget.activate                                        jquery-ui.min.js:12
a.widget.move                                            jquery-ui.min.js:12
a.widget.next                                            jquery-ui.min.js:12
a.widget._move                                           jquery-ui.min.js:12
a.widget._create.element.addClass.attr.attr.bind.bind.d  jquery-ui.min.js:12
f.event.dispatch                                         jquery-1.7.1.min.js:3
f.event.add.h.handle.i
```

i'm using version 1.7.1 of jQuery and Version 1.8.12 of jquery UI

On the demo page of jquery ui autocomplete the keydown works well.

Any ideas what's going wrong with my constellation?

It doesn't make a difference to use remote or local data.

Best regards,
Ramo

Comment: You should show your data structure. This syntax is very heavy, you could use formatItem() instead. I'll show you an example if you provide a mock data.

Comment: I've added some static data to the above code. i get the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I really can make your code working. So I tried to rewrote it in a more simplier way. The problem is render functions only accept strings, not html element. So I add a listener to render the list after its generation (fired on keydown() event).

My thought is you are doing it the wrong way.

- why adding another class on those items ? they have already one,  so they can be styled.
- why transforming them into a nodes ? just add a click() event on them

Could you explain your functional goal ?

```
// Your list of links
var redirectLinks = {'Ruby': '1234.com', 'Asp': '1235.com'};
function redirect(url) {
  // TODO implement window.location=url or whatever you like
  if(redirectLinks[url] != undefined) {
    alert('redirecting to '+url+' => '+redirectLinks[url]);
  }
}

$('.searchfield').each(function () {
  $(this).autocomplete(availableTags, { 
    minLength: 1,
    change: function(event, ui) {
      console.log('this change event doesnt seem to be fired');        
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      console.log('this select event doesnt seem to be fired');        
    }
  });
  // After the list construction
  $(this).keyup(function(e){      
    if (e.which == 13) { // typing enter validates the input => autocompletechange
      console.log('validating input '+$(this).val());    
      redirect($(this).val());
    }  
    var $list = $('.ac_results:first ul').find('li');
    $list.click(function() { // adding an event on suggestion => autocompleteselect
      console.log('clicking on suggestion '+$(this).text());    
      redirect($(this).text());
    });
  }); 


});
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for me. now i get the "default" behavior of the ui autocomplete plugin. there is no link for each entry in the resultset. if i click on an item, i just get the value into the "input field"

Comment: so what i try to achieve is the following: i'll type in a search word and get an autocompletion list. with my above code i can hover over each resultlistentry click on it and get redirected to another page. this should also be possible when interacting with the keyboard, and not with the mouse... so type in the word, get the result list, press the push button (arrow down) select an entry, hit return and get redirected to the proper page. i'm getting a remote jsonstring which assembly is: {'keytitle', '1234'}. so a listresult should be labeled with keytitle but link to a page with id 1234

Comment: Hi, thank you for your ado, but somehow this is not the same behaviour as in my code above. in my code each entry represented a link (<a...></a>) and clicking on it got me to the proper page. the jsonstring i've got is {'keytitle', '1234'}. in my code above: item.value is evaluated to '1234' and item.label to 'keytitle' . but how can i achieve to get the "item" variable now?

Comment: check the parameter of the redirect() function. Otherwise, you can check the $(input).val() or add an attribute in the click() event

Comment: hm, i'm not getting it: here's a outline of the reponse data i get: {"label":"Tosca","value":"605243","thumb":""} . how can i invoke now label to get "Tosca", or value to get "60.." or thumb to get this value?

Comment: vaugham: where is .ac_results referencing to? i'm using the jquery ui autocomplete. and if i search in the jquery-ui.min.js file for that string, i can't find anything

Comment: Look at the generated html by autocomplete, ac_results is the class of the generated suggestions list. You can choose your own.

Comment: really strange: if i'm using your snippet, i get     "Uncaught TypeError: Property 'source' of object #<Object> is not a function
/web/app_dev.php/:135 this change event doesnt seem to be fired" in the console

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6893/discussion-between-ramo-and-vaugham)